# Putty terminal windows on Windows7s don't close when the sessions terminate. Why?

Tags: command-line, 16.04, ssh, windows-7, putty

My machines:

1. An Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS (GNU/Linux 3.10.105-0-pine64-longsleep aarch64) on a pine64 board
2. An Ubuntu 16.04 LTS on a SONY machine
3. An Ubuntu 16.04 LTS on an unknown machine
4. Tow windows7 computers with Putty0.67

---

I'm running an Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS (GNU/Linux 3.10.105-0-pine64-longsleep aarch64) on a pine64 board. I do SSH to the Ubuntu from Putty terminals on two Windows7s.

The annoying behavior I hate is the putty terminal windows connecting to the Ubuntu on the pine64 never close when the connections terminate, although they close correctly when they connect to other Ubuntu16.04 machines.

I'm setting putty to close the terminal windows when the connections exit clearly --clear exit-- as showed in the documentation of Putty: https://the.earth.li/~sgtatham/putty/0.68/htmldoc/Chapter4.html#config-closeonexit

Additionally, when I reboot the Ubuntu on the pine64, the putty terminals also don't show any error message for loosing the connection unexpectedly, though I got the error message when I reboot other Ubuntu machines. I understand the error message should appear when reboot is done.

Regarding these situations, the Putty doesn't appear to recognize that the sessions exit. I think some irregular setting on the Ubuntu on the pine64 causes this behavior, but I don't know what it is.

Do any of you have any idea of forcing the Ubuntu on pine64 to terminate the session with "clear exit"?

Comment: Start by comparing the `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`s of the systems. Are they identical? Which versions of SSH are installed?

Comment: I took diff for `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` files and there are only unrelated differences between them.